# One printable latin1 char in valid full utf8 sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, utf-8, emoji

I'm trying to insert an email address into Postgres using the libpq driver for Golang. The error message is

> Unable to execute the query. pq: character with byte sequence 0xf0 0x9f 0x9a 0x80 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"

In fact, only 0xf0 is a printable latin1 char, I don't think those are latin1 chars. The full sequence is the :rocket: UTF8 char.

This is the email address.

```golang
author := " Steven Duncan  <steven.duncan@gmail.com>"
```

I am trying to use a SanitizeSQL function to catch this error but it is not catching the

```golang
sqlStatement := `INSERT INTO logs (author) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id`

sql_with_args, err := SanitizeSQL(sqlStatement, author)
```

This is the code (full demo on [google play](https://go.dev/play/p/26uf8omhqnu))

```golang
func SanitizeSQL(sql string, args ...any) (string, error) {
    query, err := NewQuery(sql)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return query.Sanitize(args...)
}

type Part any

type Query struct {
    Parts []Part
}

// utf.DecodeRune returns the utf8.RuneError for errors. But that is actually rune U+FFFD -- the unicode replacement
// character. utf8.RuneError is not an error if it is also width 3.
//
// https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/1380
const replacementcharacterwidth = 3

func (q *Query) Sanitize(args ...any) (string, error) {
    argUse := make([]bool, len(args))
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

    for _, part := range q.Parts {
        var str string
        switch part := part.(type) {
        case string:
            str = part
        case int:
            argIdx := part - 1

            if argIdx < 0 {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("first sql argument must be > 0")
            }

            if argIdx >= len(args) {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("insufficient arguments")
            }
            arg := args[argIdx]
            switch arg := arg.(type) {
            case nil:
                str = "null"
            case int64:
                str = strconv.FormatInt(arg, 10)
            case float64:
                str = strconv.FormatFloat(arg, 'f', -1, 64)
            case bool:
                str = strconv.FormatBool(arg)
            case []byte:
                str = QuoteBytes(arg)
            case string:
                str = QuoteString(arg)
            case time.Time:
                str = arg.Truncate(time.Microsecond).Format("'2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999Z07:00:00'")
            default:
                return "", fmt.Errorf("invalid arg type: %T", arg)
            }
            argUse[argIdx] = true

            // Prevent SQL injection via Line Comment Creation
            // https://github.com/jackc/pgx/security/advisories/GHSA-m7wr-2xf7-cm9p
            str = " " + str + " "
        default:
            return "", fmt.Errorf("invalid Part type: %T", part)
        }
        buf.WriteString(str)
    }

    for i, used := range argUse {
        if !used {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("unused argument: %d", i)
        }
    }
    return buf.String(), nil
}

func NewQuery(sql string) (*Query, error) {
    l := &sqlLexer{
        src:     sql,
        stateFn: rawState,
    }

    for l.stateFn != nil {
        l.stateFn = l.stateFn(l)
    }

    query := &Query{Parts: l.parts}

    return query, nil
}

func QuoteString(str string) string {
    return "'" + strings.ReplaceAll(str, "'", "''") + "'"
}

func QuoteBytes(buf []byte) string {
    return `'\x` + hex.EncodeToString(buf) + "'"
}

type sqlLexer struct {
    src     string
    start   int
    pos     int
    nested  int // multiline comment nesting level.
    stateFn stateFn
    parts   []Part
}

type stateFn func(*sqlLexer) stateFn

func rawState(l *sqlLexer) stateFn {
    for {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
        l.pos += width

        switch r {
        case 'e', 'E':
            nextRune, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if nextRune == '\'' {
                l.pos += width
                return escapeStringState
            }
        case '\'':
            return singleQuoteState
        case '"':
            return doubleQuoteState
        case '$':
            nextRune, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if '0' <= nextRune && nextRune <= '9' {
                if l.pos-l.start > 0 {
                    l.parts = append(l.parts, l.src[l.start:l.pos-width])
                }
                l.start = l.pos
                return placeholderState
            }
        case '-':
            nextRune, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if nextRune == '-' {
                l.pos += width
                return oneLineCommentState
            }
        case '/':
            nextRune, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if nextRune == '*' {
                l.pos += width
                return multilineCommentState
            }
        case utf8.RuneError:
            if width != replacementcharacterwidth {
                if l.pos-l.start > 0 {
                    l.parts = append(l.parts, l.src[l.start:l.pos])
                    l.start = l.pos
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

func singleQuoteState(l *sqlLexer) stateFn {
    for {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
        l.pos += width

        switch r {
        case '\'':
            nextRune, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if nextRune != '\'' {
                return rawState
            }
            l.pos += width
        case utf8.RuneError:
            if width != replacementcharacterwidth {
                if l.pos-l.start > 0 {
                    l.parts = append(l.parts, l.src[l.start:l.pos])
                    l.start = l.pos
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

func doubleQuoteState(l *sqlLexer) stateFn {
    for {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
        l.pos += width

        switch r {
        case '"':
            nextRune, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if nextRune != '"' {
                return rawState
            }
            l.pos += width
        case utf8.RuneError:
            if width != replacementcharacterwidth {
                if l.pos-l.start > 0 {
                    l.parts = append(l.parts, l.src[l.start:l.pos])
                    l.start = l.pos
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

// placeholderState consumes a placeholder value. The $ must have already has
// already been consumed. The first rune must be a digit.
func placeholderState(l *sqlLexer) stateFn {
    num := 0

    for {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
        l.pos += width

        if '0' <= r && r <= '9' {
            num *= 10
            num += int(r - '0')
        } else {
            l.parts = append(l.parts, num)
            l.pos -= width
            l.start = l.pos
            return rawState
        }
    }
}

func escapeStringState(l *sqlLexer) stateFn {
    for {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
        l.pos += width

        switch r {
        case '\\':
            _, width = utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            l.pos += width
        case '\'':
            nextRune, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if nextRune != '\'' {
                return rawState
            }
            l.pos += width
        case utf8.RuneError:
            if width != replacementcharacterwidth {
                if l.pos-l.start > 0 {
                    l.parts = append(l.parts, l.src[l.start:l.pos])
                    l.start = l.pos
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

func oneLineCommentState(l *sqlLexer) stateFn {
    for {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
        l.pos += width

        switch r {
        case '\\':
            _, width = utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            l.pos += width
        case '\n', '\r':
            return rawState
        case utf8.RuneError:
            if width != replacementcharacterwidth {
                if l.pos-l.start > 0 {
                    l.parts = append(l.parts, l.src[l.start:l.pos])
                    l.start = l.pos
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

func multilineCommentState(l *sqlLexer) stateFn {
    for {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
        l.pos += width

        switch r {
        case '/':
            nextRune, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if nextRune == '*' {
                l.pos += width
                l.nested++
            }
        case '*':
            nextRune, width := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.src[l.pos:])
            if nextRune != '/' {
                continue
            }

            l.pos += width
            if l.nested == 0 {
                return rawState
            }
            l.nested--

        case utf8.RuneError:
            if width != replacementcharacterwidth {
                if l.pos-l.start > 0 {
                    l.parts = append(l.parts, l.src[l.start:l.pos])
                    l.start = l.pos
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to edit the question to fix a grammar/broken sentence but SO says an error is occurring submitting the edit

Comment: You are trying to insert a Unicode character  into a latin1 column. The error message is telling you it cannot be done, which is correct.

Comment: @GSerg indeed you are correct but please explain something. My server_encoding is Latin1 (I just discovered) and the client_encoding is  UTF8 (I also just discovered). However, I'm using two different postgres drivers on the same db (for testing purposes) and one of them inserts the email address without error? How is that possible?

Comment: Also why are you sanitizing and injecting the data? Just bind parameters properly. This whole code is nonsense and unnecessary. When you bind parameters properly, you don't need to escape or sanitize or quote anything, because the code and data are separated from each other.

Comment: `one of them inserts the email address without error` - it doesn't. It could ignore the mismatch and just dump the bytes into the column, which would appear as garbage characters when you view it with something else. If you then use the same driver and instruct it to reinterpret the nonsencical bytes as utf-8, it may.

Comment: What LATIN1 string do you expect to be stored when you insert a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store a character that cannot be encoded in LATIN1 in a database with encoding LATIN1. There is really only one good solution: create a new database with `UTF8` encoding, dump your database and restore it into the `UTF8` database.